# org.json.JSONException: No value for Value

Tags: parsing

I'm trying to parse json object into my andorid app but it gives me this exception..

```
5-02 22:16:34.711    1420-1437/com.tutecentral.restfulapiclient D/JSONParser => parseDepartment﹕ No value for Value
05-02 22:16:34.711    1420-1437/com.tutecentral.restfulapiclient W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for Value
05-02 22:16:34.735    1420-1437/com.tutecentral.restfulapiclient W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
05-02 22:16:34.735    1420-1437/com.tutecentral.restfulapiclient W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
05-02 22:16:34.739    1420-1437/com.tutecentral.restfulapiclient W/System.err﹕ at com.tutecentral.restfulapiclient.JSONParser.parseDepartment(JSONParser.java:22)
05-02 22:16:34.739    1420-1437/com.tutecentral.restfulapiclient W/System.err﹕ at com.tutecentral.restfulapiclient.DeptActivity$AsyncLoadDeptDetails.doInBackground(DeptActivity.java:64)
05-02 22:16:34.739    1420-1437/com.tutecentral.restfulapiclient W/System.err﹕ at com.tutecentral.restfulapiclient.DeptActivity$AsyncLoadDeptDetails.doInBackground(DeptActivity.java:48)
05-02 22:16:34.739    1420-1437/com.tutecentral.restfulapiclient W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
```

My json

```
{
    "name": "JSONWebAPI",
    "description": "JSON API for android appliation",
    "url": "http://HAMAD/New_ExampleWEB/handler1.ashx",
    "interfaces": [
    {
    "name": "Service1",
    "methods": [
    {
    "name": "CreateNewAccount",
    "parameters": [
    {
    "name": "firstName",
    "type": "string"
    },
    {
    "name": "lastName",
    "type": "string"
    },
    {
    "name": "userName",
    "type": "string"
    },
    {
    "name": "password",
    "type": "string"
    }
    ],
    "returnvalue": "void"
    },
    {
    "name": "GetUserDetails",
    "parameters": [
    {
    "name": "userName",
    "type": "string"
    }
    ],
    "returnvalue": "object"
    },
    {
    "name": "UserAuthentication",
    "parameters": [
    {
    "name": "userName",
    "type": "string"
    },
    {
    "name": "passsword",
    "type": "string"
    }
    ],
    "returnvalue": "boolean"
    },
    {
    "name": "GetDepartmentDetails",
    "parameters": [],
    "returnvalue": "object"
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
    }
```

and this is my code

```
public ArrayList<DeptTable> parseDepartment(JSONObject object)
{
    ArrayList<DeptTable> arrayList=new ArrayList<DeptTable>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray=object.getJSONArray("Value");
        JSONObject jsonObj=null;
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
            jsonObj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            arrayList.add(new DeptTable(jsonObj.getInt("no"), jsonObj.getString("name")));
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("JSONParser => parseDepartment", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

I'm using this tutorial

http://www.tutecentral.com/restful-api-for-android-part-1/

http://www.tutecentral.com/restful-api-for-android-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

getJSONArray("Value") will get the array that follow it, like this:

```
"Value" : [ "test1", "test2" ]
```

There is no array in your JSON that is prefixed by "Value" and therefore it fails. It is a bit hard to tell where exactly "Value" should be without more details.

Comment: I downloaded the files exactly from the tutorial, everything. How can I provide you with more details so you can help me? To be honest, this my first time to use json